# Conflict with Huawei HMS plugin in android with gradle 7.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm getting this error with Gradle `7.0` while it was working fine for `6.8.3`

agcp-gradle-7-error

AGCPlugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugAGCPlugin' (type 'AGCPluginTask').

  - Type 'AGCPluginTask' property 'randomEncryptComponent' of type boolean shouldn't be annotated with @Optional.

    Reason: Properties of primitive type cannot be optional.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Remove the @Optional annotation.
    2. Use the java.lang.Boolean type instead.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#cannot_use_optional_on_primitive_types for more details about this problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I no longer get any errors with:

```
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.2.300'
```

and

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Comment: The last version is not the com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.300 ?

Comment: Huawei documentations is not up to date https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001051007083, they suggest classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.301

The version in the accepted answer 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.2.300' works with Gradle 7
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

Currently Gradle 7.0 is not supported. As I hear, it will be supported at the end of June.

Comment: thanks, but do you have any reference or any workaround for it?

Comment: @Moataz, it's everything, that I know. I create a ticket in AppGallery ticket system as developer and their TechnocalSupport gave me this answer.

Comment: @mohax I found such a ticket a while back, but kind find it anymore. Perhaps you can link it here? Edit: https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201542029574270175

Comment: @jayeffkay, ticket was not on forum, but in console built-in system, so only I can view it(